# DRF asking for CSRF Token with TokenAuthentication as the only auth method

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

My only auth system for DRF is TokenAuthentication and it is still asking for a CSRF Token on a function based view. I'm not having this problem with class based views.

settings.py:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
        'rest_framework.renderers.BrowsableAPIRenderer',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication'
    ]
}
```

views.py:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
@authentication_classes([TokenAuthentication])
def submit_vote(request):
    # ...
```

On Postman's POST request:

```
Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.): /rest/submit_vote/
[04/Nov/2020 02:05:38] "POST /rest/submit_vote/ HTTP/1.1" 403 2864
```

*What?!*

I don't have any pending migration.

Comment: csrf is not the same as auth.

Comment: Then what? DRF documentation: "If you're using SessionAuthentication you'll need to include valid CSRF tokens for any POST, PUT, PATCH or DELETE operations.", I'm not using SessionAuthentication.

Comment: DRF will not give you a CSRF token missing exception unless you override things for it. Better check your URL so that you are probably requesting some other views.

Answer (score 2):

The CSRF is enabled in DRF only if the `SessionAuthentication` is used. User needs to be logged in with session, to force DRF to check CSRF.

If you are using `TokenAuthentication` the DRF will not send CSRF to client and will not require CSRF in cookies in the response.

If you have `Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.)`  then probably there is some problem in your code / browser:

- please double-check that there is no `csrf_token` tag used in any of your views, if you have such a view, it will force Django to send you a CSRF cookie
- please double-check that you don't have CSRF token in cookies (just clear all cookies), search for `X-CSRFToken`,
- please check how server response headers look like, is there a CSRF cookie? it shouldn't be there,
- please check how your request headers look like, are you sending any cookies in the header?

If you still have problems, please provide a minimal working example to reproduce this behavior, and I will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Any POST, PUT, PATCH or DELETE or requests in Django require a CSRF token. If you are sending requests using Postman, [check this Medium post to see how to set the CSRF token in Postman](https://medium.com/hackernoon/automatically-set-csrf-token-in-postman-django-tips-c9ec8eb9eb5b).

You could also disable the `csrf_token` validation, by adding the `csrf_exempt` decorator. **Not recommended.**

```py
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

@csrf_exempt
def my_view(request):
    return HttpResponse('Hello world')
```

Comment: Why I didn't have any problem regarding CSRF Token with class based views? I did use POST and DELETE.

Comment: DRF applying `csrf_exempt` decorator behind the scenes. Moreover, this is *bare Django view*, which is not capable of handling DRF permissions and auth classes

Comment: @GonzaloDambra, hope this answer helped you. Please accept and upvote if it did :). As for your question, Arrakal is right, DRF applies `csrf_exempt` decorator behind the scenes if you do not use `SessionAuthentication`.

Answer (score 0):

In a project which is using Token auth for front-end and session auth for Django back-end.

I found out that as long as you don't have session cookie in your browser DRF is happy with bearer tokens only, but if you login to admin , then bearer token needs CSRF token also.